# Accessing the model's attribute translations when displaying error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've successfully created my he.yml to localize my model's attributes names,
example:

```
      attributes:
       vendor:
        name: שם ספק
        counter_number: מספר חשבונית
        phone: טלפון
        address: כתובת
```

Now, displaying labels in forms using simple_form's f.input, displays it correctly, the translated value of each attribute.

the problem is, displaying errors after validation, using

```
<% @vendor.errors.each do |attribute, error| %>
```

|attribute| for error "counter_number" for example, is displayed: "counter_number".
not the translated one at the locale file [which as i mentioned previously, configured and loaded successfully].
I appended errors in a ul.errors, as shown in this screenshot:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@vendor.errors.messages do |attribute, errors|
  translated_attribute = Vendor.human_attribute_name(attribute)
  errors = errors.join(", ")
end
```

I've tested this with my `User` model:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following is just an example to complete your provided code.

```
<% @vendor.errors.each do |attribute, error| %>
  <strong><%= t("activerecord.attributes.#{@vendor.class.to_s.underscore}.#{attribute}") %>:</strong>
  <%= error.messages.to_sentence %>
<% end %>
```

Maybe there is an easier approach than this.